# Move an object (Mario-style) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a near-perfect object movement in jQuery. I have tried a few ways but none seems to be perfect. I have tried:

1. Press key -> Move by x amount of pixels
2. Press key -> Animate by x amount of pixels

Moving a few pixels at a time makes it look laggy and bad. I think we can all agree on that. I then later found someone, who used animate to change the axis' coordinates (basically changing an object's left attribute to be bigger or smaller):

http://jsfiddle.net/2L86bdw0/1/

```
$('.user').animate({
    left: '+=500'
},{
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'linear',
}).dequeue();
```

This basically moves it right 500 pixels over 1000 milliseconds. This makes the movement extremely smooth and seems like the best way to do this.

However. Try holding down right arrow and then left. It should start to move left, which it does. However, when you then remove your finger from the left arrow, it should start to move right again (assuming you still hold down the right arrow). However, it does not.

I have been looking for the best possible way to do this, however, I have not been able to find a good solution. I want to create a Mario-styled website, but I cannot make movement be near-perfect. Help appreciated.

Comment: If you want to create games in JS check out http://phaser.io/. It's much better suited to the task than jQuery

Comment: I would consider starting with a 60fps (or 30fps) game loop based off of `setTimeout`.

Comment: They use canvases though. I'm not interested in that.

Comment: if you're not interested in canvases, what is the exact goal of it? If you're trying to accomplish such, I think everyone will pretend to imagine that you are trying to develop some sort of games. If you're not, then the cleverest solution is to **store** pressed keys in objects and, on keyup, detect what is the movement following a set of rules.

Comment: @briosheje Can you store the pressed keys in an object, then remove the key when keyup event has been fired, and it will still know if the pressed keys are pressed? Of course it would, but what I mean is, is it fast enough and would it work in a real world scenario? Also, I am trying to do this with HTML elements instead of an canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to keep track of the current keys being pressed. My first thought was a stack, but that wouldn't work because you could release keys in a different order that you pressed them. So I am thinking that you could do this with an array or linked list. Push keys onto the list when they are pressed, and remove them when they are released. Process the keys backwards. So in the main loop you would check which key is last in the list and process its direction.

Comment: And then keep using the animate()?

Comment: @Snorlax I threw together an example using an array. http://jsfiddle.net/2L86bdw0/7/ it can be done better, but this is what I was talking about.

Comment: Oh hell yeah, znick! That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How would you go on about checking, if the object has reached the left or right side of the screen? I already threw an if-statement around my whole keydown and keyup, which checks if the left attribute of the object is lesser or greater than 0 or the screen's width, however, since it doesn't check every millisecond and doesn't update all the time, the left attribute can be less than 0 and greater than the screen's width.

Comment: Also there's an error in this. When you hold down up arrow to make it jump, but only hit the left/right arrow once, it will move the entire 500 pixels. As soon as you let go of the up key, it stops moving in that direction.

Comment: I don't have time to help with much more, but to fix the bug I simply added a function to check if the user was pressing the left/right keys. When they finish a jump, if they are not pressing those keys they will stop moving. http://jsfiddle.net/2L86bdw0/9/

Comment: Nice! Works perfect. Thanks, znick.

Answer (score 2):

Game engines solve this problem by using different states for keypresses:

keypress, keydown, keyup

keypress is first loop that a key was pressed.
keydown is 2nd+ loop that a key has been active.
keyup is the first loop that a key that was previously keydown is no longer pressed.

The basics that you're going to have to emulate are looking to see if a new key is pressed since the last loop and use that new key as the direction to animate. And keyUp should look if a key is no longer pressed since the last update and then slow down the object being manipulated to slow it down eventually stopping it (if you're sticking with mario acceleration and not just instantly stopping).

I would suggest storing a "lastkey" variable and comparing that against your current keydowns.

Comment: Can you create an example though?